# System Verilog attaching vector [10..0] to integer

Tags: verilog

```
module  rocket_move (   
    input   logic   clk,
    input   logic   resetN,
    input    logic signed   [10:0]  spaceship_X,  
    input    logic signed   [10:0]  spaceship_Y, 
    output   logic signed   [10:0]  rocket_topLeftX, // output the top left corner 
    output   logic signed   [10:0]  rocket_topLeftY  // can be negative 
);
// a module used to generate the  rocket trajectory.  

int x = spaceship_X[10:0];
int y = spaceship_Y[10:0];
```

Im trying to attach a rocket bitmap to the center of spaceship bitmap which i've already build and works,
spaceship_[10..0] is vector that holds position on axis X and Y of a spaceship, im trying to use a variable for future calculations but i get error every time, i've tried to do calculations straigh with  spaceship_X[10..0], in that case i dont get an error but cant see the rocket bitmap either. thanks in advance

"Error (10748): Verilog HDL error at rocket_move.sv(26): expression in variable declaration assignment to x must be constant"

Comment: Im using Quartus, i edited the code and left only the importatnt things , line 26  is         int x = spaceship_X[10:0]; i solved the problem by using " <= " instead "=" further in code , thank you

Comment: If this is the line causing the problem,
int x = spaceship_X[10:0];
Then It is because the tool is expecting an initial value to a variable on the line where it's declared, not a continuous assignment.
Use a continuous assignment further down in the code (not the line where its declared)
assign x = spaceship_X;

Answer (score 1):

Assigning an `int` at its declaration will give it an initial value at time zero. At the time off assignment the spaceship X/Y value is still its type’s default value.

Assuming x/y are only driven by spaceship X/Y you code do the following:

```
int x,y;
always_comb begin
  x = spaceship_X[10:0];
  y = spaceship_Y[10:0];
end
```

Or:
int x,y;
assign x = spaceship_X[10:0];
assign y = spaceship_Y[10:0];

If x/y have mutual assignment, then handle all the assignment conditions within the `always_comb`. If the variables are synchronous, then use `always_ff @(posedge clk)` block with non-blocking assignment (`<=`).